# MAMP 3.5 Mac Update SSL

Tags: php, ssl, mamp, php-openssl

I try to upgrade OpenSSL from 0.9.8 to 1.1.1t
With brew, I updated curl with no problem after reading those explications (https://github.com/lunr/mamp-curl-tls). But even if curl library has been updated, I didn't found how to update openssl.
My goal is to send email with phpMailer and TLS 1.2 security !
I try to copy openssl.so from
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1t/bin to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226

I edit /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.6.10 and add the line extension=openssl.so

But in phpinfo(), OpenSSL version is always 0.9.8zh !

Could you help me to solve that.
Many thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: You mean you are using MAMP php5.6.10 ??

Comment: Yes I work with MAMP 3.5 on Mac OS with php 5.6.10